# Autodesk DM API: Is Retry appropriate here?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I've got an application that's been working for a long time.
Recently we created a new app/keys for it, and it's behaving strangely.
(I did figure out the scope requirements had been put in place. I am requesting bucket:create bucket:read data:read data:write).

When I upload a file to a bucket, I've traditionally called done the call to get the object details afterwards, to verify that it's successfully uploaded.
With the new key, I am intermittently getting this error:

GetObjectDetails: InternalServerError {"fault":{"faultstring":"Execution of ServiceCallout servicecallout-auth-acm-request failed. Reason: timeout occurred servicecallout-auth-acm-request","detail":{"errorcode":"steps.servicecallout.ExecutionFailed"}}}

Is this something I should be re-trying with a sleep in between? or is it indicative of something wrong with the upload?

(FYI - putting in a retry seems to have have resolved this for me, but I still don't know if that's the right answer - and if this issue might happen on other calls).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that the service requires a slight delay between a put object and a get, so I would suggest either use a timer or a retry as you mentioned. However a successful response from the upload should be enough to ensure your object has been placed to the bucket without the need to double check.